# About Client-Server Log-in System

Tags: client-server

> 

I want to know a programming in C about the log-in system, like signing in with password and email and getting access. can anyone please help me? Thank You!!

Comment: please..guys..help me with this

Comment: Can you be more especific with your question? Are you writting a program (client-server) in C, and you want to log the logins, signins, etc, right?

Comment: yes...is that possible?

Comment: https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/12511859_1260734040608870_2122985120_n.jpg?oh=18630dd25891fe35d9d551c17a626040&oe=5695C3F1
here is the picture of the output..i need the source code

Comment: can some one help me??

Comment: so you don't want to log the events, you just want a program to do the action...  [check this, for example](http://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/)

Comment: thank you for your help..it solved what i wanted....but can you help me with the "log the events" too??

Comment: is it possible that the program we make can work as are a reminder which reminds us by sending email in our mails??

Answer (score 0):

TO SEND MAIL: You could invoke your local **MTA** directly using

> popen()

and feed it **RFC822-compliant** text. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
int sendmail(const char *to, const char *from, const char *subject, const char *message)
{
    int retval = -1;
    FILE *mailpipe = popen("/usr/lib/sendmail -t", "w");
    if (mailpipe != NULL) {
        fprintf(mailpipe, "To: %s\n", to);
        fprintf(mailpipe, "From: %s\n", from);
        fprintf(mailpipe, "Subject: %s\n\n", subject);
        fwrite(message, 1, strlen(message), mailpipe);
        fwrite(".\n", 1, 2, mailpipe);
        pclose(mailpipe);
        retval = 0;
     }
     else {
         perror("Failed to invoke sendmail");
     }
     return retval;
}
```

AND TO LOG THE EVENTS: for exemple you can open a file and write whatever...

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* print some text */
const char *text = "Write this to the file";
fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", text);

/* print integers and floats */
int i = 1;
float py = 3.1415927;
fprintf(f, "Integer: %d, float: %f\n", i, py);

/* printing single chatacters */
char c = 'A';
fprintf(f, "A character: %c\n", c);

fclose(f);
```